# Oraclize on Ropsten

Tags: oracles

I try to use oracle? I choose Oraclize for my tests on Ropsten.

I try this exemple (KrakenPriceTicker.sol) http://dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/#gist=9817193e5b05206847ed1fcd1d16bd1d&version=soljson-v0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.js

I'm connected with MetaMask on Ropsten and i have no problème to deploye the contract.
When i deployed in events section i can see :

```
newOraclizeQuery{
  "description": "Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer.."
}
```

Transaction : https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xdfae8ba03723a879055fe99e57b64d4e67976bcfc11fba490724eb664b1f39a0#eventlog

But the value stay 0 and the callback function is never call :'(

I don't know what i must do... ?

Answer (score 3):

Your contract __callback function was called after the specified delay here https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x05465012dad240da337cf34638ddcd67752bb79f5948496c6e8123a5641b0fd3

(You can see the __callback signature in the transaction input data)

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i don't undesertand why doesn't work the first time : https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x5c167ef5bddcc39d49cdc240fd48b140ee23a5b192fff73a1d839fd9cf356b15 "Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee" but i d'ont add Eth between the first and the second time

Answer (score 0):

The first price of using oraclize is free, while you have to pay for second or later ones. You can check [pricing](http://docs.oraclize.it/#pricing) at the docs of oraclize. Hope this helps.